# Prove matrix inequality in inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, inner-products

If $\{u_i\}_{i=1,\dots,d}$, $\{v_i\}_{i=1,\dots,d}$ are two sets of vectors in an inner product space such that
\begin{equation}
\langle u_i, v_j\rangle= \delta_{ij}\;,
\end{equation}
then prove that the two $d\times d$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with entries defined by
\begin{equation}
A_{ij}=\langle u_i, u_j\rangle\;,\qquad B_{ij}=\langle v_i, v_j\rangle\;,
\end{equation}
satisfy the matrix inequality
\begin{equation}
A\geq B^{-1}\;,
\end{equation}
i.e. $A-B^{-1}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal V$ be the span of all $v_i$s. Decompose each $u_i$ into the sum $x_i+w_i$, where $x_i\in V^\perp$ and $w_i\in\mathcal V$. Then
\begin{cases}
\langle w_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij},\\
A_{ij}=\langle x_i,x_j\rangle+\langle w_i,w_j\rangle,\\
B_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle.
\end{cases}
Let $\mathcal X$ be the span of all $x_i$s. Suppose $\dim\mathcal V=p$ and $\dim\mathcal X=q$. By picking any two orthonormal bases of $V$ and $X$, we may rewrite the above in matrix form:
\begin{cases}
V^\ast W=I,\\
A=X^\ast X+W^\ast W,\\
B=V^\ast V,
\end{cases}
where $V$ and $W$ are $p\times d$ and $X$ is $q\times d$. Since $p=\dim\mathcal V\le d$, the condition $V^\ast W=I$ implies that $p$ must be equal to $d$ and hence $V^\ast=W^{-1}$. Thus $B^{-1}=W^\ast W\le A$.